# python dynamically append keys and values to a JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

Im trying to generate a json file with dynamic values.

**sample format**

```
  {
  "dynamic_key1": [
  
              { "Name1":"dynamic_value1" ,
              "Name2":"dynamic_value2" }],
   
  "dynamic_key2": [
  
              { "Name3":"dynamic_value3" ,
              "Name4":"dynamic_value4" }]
  
   }
```

How to generate a json file based up on the sample format

input data should be read from a dataframe like following[image]:

Comment: Google "convert dataframe to JSON"

Comment: @kankan256 yeah tried that but the result is not expected as the sample format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "column1": ["dynamic_key1", "dynamic_key2"],
        "column2": ["dynamic_value1", "dynamic_value3"],
        "column3": ["dynamic_value2", "dynamic_value4"]
    }
)


print(df)

keys, res = df["column1"], {}

for i, key in enumerate(df["column1"]):
    res[key] = []
    tmp = {}
    for j in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        tmp["Name{}".format(j)] = df.iloc[i, j]
    res[key].append(tmp)


print(json.dumps(res, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Comment: yeah this works thanks, instead of printing json i just want to save it as json file